# How to create HSQLDB database that only exists during JVM lifetime?

Tags: hsqldb, in-memory-database

From the documentation I gather that a temporary database exists only for the lifetime of a single connection (not long enough), while an in-memory database is actually persistent and creates files (too long).

How do I create a database that multiple connections can access, but that isn't persistent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All HSQLDB databases are accessible from multiple connections.

An in-process database is accessible from connections in the same JVM, while a server database is also accessible from other processes.

If an in-process database or a server database is created with the `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:dbname` connection URL, no files are created and the database is not persistent.